# Opening a OneNote Page URL in terminal on mac

Tags: terminal, alfred

I am trying to open a onenote page directly using a shell script on mac.

I know this is possible using Alfred by passing the 2nd url (beginning with `onenote:`) when right clicking a onenote page and 'copy link to section':

[image]

If I try and do the same thing in terminal by passing in a url: `open /Applications/Microsoft\ OneNote.app -u "onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/mypageurl"` then it doesn't seem to work (here I am using the `-u` flag to try and pass in as a url, but I have tried also with `--args`.

Is there any way to do this? do I need to encode it as UTF8 or something before passing in as an arg?

Thanks

---

Comment: Canf you right-click, copy the link and the paste it into the question so we know which format such links have? Also, what does happen with `open 'onenote:https…'`?

Comment: purely using open with the url throws: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString replaceCharactersInRange:withString:]: nil argument'`

Comment: re link: `onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/abcdefabcdefabcd/Documents/MyNoteBook/notename&section-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678}&page-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-12345678}&end`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

Use:

```
open 'onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/mypageurl'
```

When reading the URL, `open` will interpret `onenote:` as a custom URL scheme and open OneNote with the link you provided.

Other apps support custom URL schemes too. For example, Mail uses `message:` and Evernote uses `evernote:`.

For more information on custom URL schemes, see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/defining-a-custom-url-scheme-for-your-app.

> do I need to encode it as UTF8 or something before passing in as an arg?

You comment that you use emojis in the notes titles, so you'll have to encode them to create a valid URL.

I've written a Bash script (tested with version 3.2.57) that takes the "raw" OneNote URL as argument and encodes it into a valid URL (I hope you can use it as a starting point for your own script):

```
#/bin/bash
unset encoded_url;
# Read every character one at a time
while read -n 1; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ []a-zA-Z0-9_\.~\!\'\(\)\;:@\&=+$,/\?%#[-] ]]; then
        # Add regular characters to the encoded url
        encoded_url="$encoded_url$REPLY";
    elif [[ $REPLY == " " ]]; then
        # Encode spaces
        encoded_url="$encoded_url%20";
    else
        # Encode other characters:
        # 1) Display hex representation with xxd
        # 2) Remove leading '00000000: '
        # 3) Remove groups of two or more white spaces and all dots
        # 4) Add % to the beginning of line
        # 5) Replace white spaces with %
        # 6) Capitalize the result
        encoded_url="$encoded_url$(echo -n $REPLY | xxd | sed 's/00000000: //; s/  *//; s/\.//; s/^/%/; s/ /%/g' | tr 'abcdefhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz' 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWZYZ')";
    fi;
done < <(echo -n "$1");
echo "$encoded_url"
```

Let's say the script is named `encodeurl`. This command:

`encodeurl 'onenote:d.docs.live.net/e1fg23a1a01a1a01/Documents/timhc22%20(1Notes).one#⬇️⬇️%202022-Q1%20⬇️⬇️&section-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890112}&page-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}&end'`

outputs this encoded URL:

`onenote:d.docs.live.net/e1fg23a1a01a1a01/Documents/timhc22%F0%9F%93%94%20(1Notes).one#%E2%AC%87%EF%B8%8F%E2%AC%87%EF%B8%8F%202022-Q1%20%E2%AC%87%EF%B8%8F%E2%AC%87%EF%B8%8F&section-id=%7B{12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890112%7D}&page-id=%7B{12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012%7D}&end`

You can use the script to encode arbitrary strings, for example:

`encodeurl '上海+中國'`

has this output:

`%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7+%E4%B8%AD%E5%9C%8B`

See https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding for more information on URL encoding.

Comment: I think this might not be working because I'm naming my page with icons. It works for pages with regular text, but not, for example: ``. Is there a way to make sure the string is parsed correctly? I tried setting this: `export LANG=C.UTF-8` but still doesn't work..

Comment: @timhc22 You can encode arbitrary characters using percent encoding (as explained here https://developers.google.com/maps/url-encoding), and you can find the relevant codes with `xxd`, for example `echo -n '' | xxd` returns `f09f 939e`, which happens to be the UTF-8 representation of the symbol.

Comment: this is helpful and is working @jaume, do you know if there any way to only have it converting the emojis though, currently running `| xxd` on the entire url changes all parts of it

Comment: @timhc22 Can you give me an example URL that contains an emoji? Feel free to change any numbers, but leave the emojis.

Comment: onenote:https://d.docs.live.net/e1fg23a1a01a1a01/Documents/timhc22/%20(1Notes).one#⬇️⬇️%202022-Q1%20⬇️⬇️&section-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-1234567890112}&page-id={12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789012}&end

Comment: @timhc22 I've added a script that converts emojis to percent encoding, check my expanded answer.

Comment: Wow that is quite something thanks! I realised from researching this, that html encoded icons can be used too, e.g.  can be replaced with `&#x1F4D4;`

Comment: I also asked this question here which you may find interesting for your own research @jaume https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71187233/how-can-i-convert-all-utf8-unicode-characters-in-a-string-to-their-relevant-code/71192339#71192339